# Column count doesn't match value count at row error in correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1136

I have written an insert query but it throws an error #1136. I checked for comma and other syntax and field with NULL values are Null allowed is also checked. Its not working. I searched for similar questions but didn't help. I have tried it both the way.

1st way:

```
INSERT INTO postdetails SET
PostId = NULL,
EventId = 1, 
FacultyId = 'hemal.desai',
InstituteId = 1,
PostTitle = 'title',
PostMsg = 'msg',
PostDate = '2014-04-22',
EventDate = '2014-04-30',
PostTime = CURRENT_TIME(),
DeleteDate = '2014-04-30',
Edited = 'No',
FileURL = 'Null',
status = 'upcoming',
reason =NULL,
oldeventdate = NULL;
```

and the 2nd way:

```
INSERT INTO postdetails (PostId, EventId, FacultyId, InstituteId, PostTitle, PostMsg, PostDate, EventDate, PostTime, DeleteDate, Edited, FileURL, status, reason, oldeventdate) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'siddhi.shah@ahduni.edu.in', '1', 'Sidddhi Mam', 'Message', '2014-04-22', '2014-04-29', CURRENT_TIME(), '2014-05-03', 'No', 'Null', 'upcoming', NULL, NULL);
```

My table structure is like this:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Here you set POSTID to Null which is actually AUTO INCREMENT. Please remove this from Column name and also from values and try to INSERT.

Comment: Thank u for your help but that doesn't work @Ilesh Patel. Problem is something else.

Comment: @SarjitDelivala Do You maybe have some triggers ?

Comment: @SarjitDelivala It might not be relevent but I notice you got php as 1 of your tags. Would it be caused by the way you run the SQL? (assuming you didn't simply type in the SQL in console)

Comment: @SarjitDelivala Can you provide the complete error message

Comment: Oh " Column count does not match value count " so name the columns that you're manipulating.

Comment: query is fine and working perfect with same table you mentioned, there  is some other issue on your side. My table engine is innodb. please check yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicate the same structure to verify for issue and it working for me with provided insert query without changing anything.

So as SarjitDelivala suggested, please check for trigger or else provide complete error with table engine detail.

Comment: plus1 for mentioning the word trigger and ending my 2+ hrs of search.